# Android Passing a variable with a dialog box which gets bypassed in OnCreate

Tags: java, android, dialog

If you read the code you can see that I've placed a Toast message after the dialog box. I want it to made so the "First" variable which is declared as public inside the same class gets its value by going through the process of the dialog box eventually getting to the if-statement and finally **displaying the Toast message inside the if-statement.**

Initially I had a method called "showDialogHOME" where all of the following code was being passed.
I thought I try it this way with the hope of solving the problem.

This code is located in OnCreate()

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"X", "O"};

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Who goes first?");
    alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item] == "X") {
                First = 1;
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Computer goes first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (items[item] == "O") {
                First = 2;
                if (First == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "2 WORKS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();

    if (First == 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Inside If", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "After If Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Toast in place of Log. Logs are much easier to add and maintain overall from the perspective of your code and also makes debugging way more effective. Also What is First? This code is a little weird...

Comment: First is a variable of the type integer. It's used so that the player can input who goes first the Computer (First == 1) or the Player (First == 2) in a game of tic-tac-toe. And Logs and Toasts don't matter to me that much. I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the lines after you create and display the AlertDialog, don't wait and executes before you set the value.

You probably want to use an event for that:

```
alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
   if (First == 1){
       Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Inside If", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else
   {
       Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "After If Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

**EDIT**
You can also try this:

```
alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item] == "X") {
                First = 1;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Computer goes first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (items[item] == "O") {
                First = 2;
                if (First == 2) {
                    //    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "2 WORKS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            dialog.dismiss();

            if (First == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Inside If", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "After If Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });

alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I don't get how this would work. The purpose of the dialog box is so the First variable can get a value of 1 or 2 according to the user's input, input entered in the dialog box.

Comment: That's right, but in your code, you don't wait for the user to select his input. This way, you display only after the user made his selection.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm asking, or at least trying to. How do I get it so the code, or the rest of the program to wait for the input of the user?

Comment: Yes, I placed your method after mine, as well as only trying to use your OnCancelListener (without OnClickListener). I don't think it works, I hope I haven't misplaced some code or anything, I can offer you a screenshot or something similar if you'd like.

Comment: minSdkVersion 14        targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Well, AlertDialog.Builder has setOnDismissListener, but its available only after sdk17.
Actually in your code, you can just put the if statement after the dialog dismissal. I've edited my answer

Comment: Splendid. Just, maybe it would be helpful for others if you re-edit your code and add a alertDialog.show(); at the bottom.